# Cannot install some apps due to unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

After I installed Ubuntu 12.04, I am not able to get Skype, Picasa , Adobe flash player and such similar applications. When I try to install these, I get this message:

```
Failed to satisfy all dependencies,The following packages have unmet dependencies
Firefox: 

 depends: libgcc1(>=1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6..3-1 is installed. 
 Software index is broken, pl use the package manager"synaptic" or run 
sudo apt_get install -f in a terminal to fix the issue first.
```

As I am not a computer expert, I am not able to follow and take action. Hence kindly let me know how to get over the problem by giving me the way I should go step by step.

Comment: Someone please help me out??

Comment: Did you try the suggested: `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```